# Is each component of a vector always a scalar?

Tags: vectors

Is it so that the components of a vector are always scalar? Is there any situation when the components of a vector are vectors and not scalars?

Comment: [Euclidean vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector) do indeed admit only scalar components.

Comment: In some compuer languages, **vector** means a list $[A,B,C,\cdots]$ where $A,B,C,\cdots$ are any type of items.